# For which Mersenne primes and Fermat primes is 2 a primitive root?

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-numbers, primitive-roots, fermat-numbers

Could you help me answering this question?

For which Mersenne primes and Fermat primes is 2 a primitive root?

I know that a $a$ is a primitive root modulo $n$ if $a$ generates $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$.

A Mersenne prime is a prime of the form $M_p=2^p-1$, with $p$ prime.

A Fermat prime is a prime of the form $2^{2^n}+1$, with $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Thank a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $2^p - 1$ be a Mersenne prime and consider the subgroup of $\mathbb{F}_{2^p-1}^\ast$ generated by 2.  It consists of $\{1, 2, 4, \ldots, 2^{p-1}\}$ since
$$2^p \equiv 1 \pmod{2^p - 1}$$
and those elements are unique since each is less than $2^p - 1$.  So that's a total of precisely $p$ elements in the subgroup $\langle 2 \rangle$.

So ask yourself: when is this the entirety of $\mathbb{F}_{2^p-1}^\ast$?

Comment: I know this answer solved the author's problem. However, you didn't actually answer the other question of when 2 is a primitive root of a Fermat prime. Maybe the author could figure out from your proof about Mersenne primes the proof about Fermat primes.

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

For $n \geq 2$, $F_n \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$, hence $2$ will be a quadratic residue so cannot be a primitive root.

For $p \geq 3$, $2^p \equiv 1\pmod{M_p}$, thus the order of $2$ modulo $M_p$ is at most $p$ so it cannot be a primitive root.

Answer (score 2):

The order of $2\bmod 2^n-1$ is clearly $n$. The order of the group however is $2^n-2$. So we need $n=2^n-2$. Clearly the only solution is $n=2$. So The Mersenne prime needed is $3$.

The order of $2\bmod 2^{k}+1$ is $2k$. The order of the group however is $2^k$. So we need $2k=2^k$. The only solution is clearly $k=2$. so the fermat prime needed is $5$.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing why the order of $2 \mod 2^k+1$ is 2k, or equivalently why 2 has an order $2^{n+1}$ vs $\phi (p)=2^{2^n}$. How is the order of 2 calculated mod Fermat prime?

Comment: It is clearly at most $2k$ and that is all we need.

Comment: According to my text, the order is exactly 2k, but I don't see why $2^{(2)2^n}\equiv 1 \mod 2^{2^n}+1$. Any calculation would greatly help me understand how the order was determined.

Comment: I mean, I can see your point that it is at most $2(2^n)$. $(2^{2^n}-1)(2^{2^n}+1)\equiv 0 \mod 2^{2^n}+1$, but I don't see how the order was known in my text.

Comment: Are you in the specific context in which the number is a fermat prime? Also you might wanna post seperately